# image result for two coordinates

Tags: vb.net, google-maps, dictionary, coordinates

is there any kind of way to input the coordinates for two locations, a startpoint and a destination, and get an image result (jpeg) of a map, say google map, showing the two locations on that same image?

I need this for a vb application
thanks!

Update:
I've successfully added the image with the two locations, but there's a tiny issue,
what if the two places are too close or too far from each other, the zooming should differ, and maybe the size too, what is the best way to manipulate these, according to the coordinates given?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Static Maps API to get the map image:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/